# Python 3. Keep a tally of letter grades

Tags: python

I need to keep a tally of each student that earned an A,B,C,D, and F. The instructions for the project ask that the user enter the LETTER grade and NOT the percentage score. So how would I keep track of each letter? Here's what I have:

```
Grades = open("ClassNameGrades.txt", "w")
count = 0
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
F=0

Grades.write=input("Enter name of class - ",)
Grades.write= input("Enter name of faculty - ")
numStudents= int(float(input("Enter the amount of students - ")))

def gradeInput(count,numStudents,A1):
    while count<numStudents:
        studentName=input("Enter name of student - ")
        Grades.write(studentName("\n"))
        studentGrade=input("Enter student letter grade - ", )
        Grades.write(studentGrade("\n"))
        count+=count
```

Comment: What result does running this script give and how does it not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

A simple if-else block should work just fine:

```
studentGrade = input("Enter student letter grade - ").upper()
if studentGrade == "A":
    A += 1
elif studentGrade == "B":
    B += 1
elif studentGrade == "C":
    C += 1
elif studentGrade == "D":
    D += 1
elif studentGrade == "F":
    F += 1
else:
    print("Error")
```

Try looking into a dictionaries for a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` for grades i.e. you can store the grades A, B, C, D, E, F as:

```
grades = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0}
```

Now you can compare the grades entered by the user. If it matches any of the grades in dict keys(A, B, C, D, E, F), then increase the count of that grade.

```
def gradeInput(count,numStudents,A1):
    while count<numStudents:
        studentName=input("Enter name of student - ")
        Grades.write(studentName("\n"))
        studentGrade=input("Enter student letter grade - ", )
        Grades.write(studentGrade("\n"))
        if studentGrade in grades:
            grades[studentGrade] += 1
        count += count
```